# Setting ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE has no effect (ROS 2 iron - windows)

Tags: ros2

I have many computers running ROS 2 Iron on the same subnet, but only certain computers should be able to discover nodes on certain other ones. I've set up the linux computers on the network to do so using the instructions on this page (https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Advanced/Improved-Dynamic-Discovery.html), which works great. When I try running the command setting the discovery range to LOCALHOST or even OFF on the Windows ROS distro (also iron), I'm still able to view nodes running on other computers, and vice versa. Any ideas what could be the issue? When I run `set | findstr ROS` in the CLI I can see that the variable has been set successfully.